# To catch a bug

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, debugging, exception

The typical workflow of catching an exception in action is get to the section of code where you suspect the exception of happening, select Debug/Exceptions, check Thrown for Common Language Runtime Exceptions, OK your way out of it, and continue execution.

This is a massive PITA.  Is there a shortcut (or a context menu) that can be configured to toggle the Thrown checkbox for the Common Language Runtime Exceptions?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958011/toggle-break-when-an-exception-is-thrown-using-macro-or-keyboard-shortcut.  No simple solution.

Comment: `bu myapp!myfunction "sxe clr;g";` :P http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105130

Comment: Perfect.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958011/toggle-break-when-an-exception-is-thrown-using-macro-or-keyboard-shortcut did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

**Ctrl+Alt+E** will bring up the exceptions menu.

**Down Arrow, Alt+T** will check/uncheck that box.

This might be the closest you will get.

Answer (score 1):

You could try writing a macro, using the [`ExceptionGroups`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte90.debugger3.exceptiongroups.aspx) property.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use visual studio macros.
[How to create Macros in Visual Studio 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kyhdt1z.aspx)