# Why should i use WinDbg?

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, visual-studio-2005, windbg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why use windbg vs the Visual Studio (VS) debugger ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105130/why-use-windbg-vs-the-visual-studio-vs-debugger)

I Use Visual Studio 2005 for C++ development.

What does WinDbg give me, that Visual Studio doesn't?

I know its good for client installations and remote debugging, as it's easy to install.

Other reasons? What are your favorite functions/commands?

Answer (score 2):

In WinDbg you could force to load PDB file that has incompatible (with EXE) checksum/date. Just write `.symopt+0x40` in command line. Visual Studio doesn't allows that.

Answer (score 1):

From [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinDbg):

WinDbg  can be used to debug user mode applications, drivers, and the operating system itself in kernel mode. It is a GUI application, but has little in common with the more well-known, but less powerful, Visual Studio Debugger.

WinDbg can be used for debugging kernel-mode memory dumps, created after what is commonly called the Blue Screen of Death which occurs when a bug check is issued. It can also be used to debug user-mode crash dumps. This is known as Post-mortem debugging.

Comment: You are able to open kernel-mode memory dumps in VS2008 as well.

Answer (score 0):

With WinDbg you have the ability to remotely debug an application with two WinDbg instances (client/server). That can be quite handy to debug an already deployed application at the customers site.